# How to call a method when a URL is hit inside UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, url, uiwebview

I am loading a URL inside UIWebView. It opens a web-page which contains some URL links. Is it possible that I call a method when particular link is clicked.

I simply want to detect the URL clicks inside UIWebView in my iOS App.

Thanks.

Comment: http://hayageek.com/uiwebview-uiwebviewdelegate-tutorial/ check this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is method in `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. Add your controller as `delegate` to `UIWebView`.

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

Then implement delegate's method:

```
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`
```

You should read it's documentation. As you can see, one parameter is navigationType, you interested only in `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Timur says add into your viewController the `UIWebViewDelegate`
Then you can use the method like this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( [[[inRequest URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"js-call"] ) {

        // Do something interesting...
       return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Then i've used a js call, but you can use also links:

```
window.location.href = "js-call:myEvent";
```